# PublishingService.publishArticle Invalid Id

Tags: apex, knowledge

Trying to publish a Knowledge Article created during a flow. So I created an `@InvocableMethod` to do it for me:

```
@InvocableMethod
public static void publishKnowledgeArticles(List<String> knowledgeIds){
    for (String articleId : knowledgeIds){
        System.debug(articleId);
        KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(articleId, true);
    }
}
```

And after the Create Records stage in our flow I call the invocable method.
The problem is that I'm getting an error: `An Apex error occurred: System.InvalidParameterValueException: Invalid ID.`

Looking at my debug logs, I see that the Id that is sent is `ka0....`.
Is that not right? What type of Id should I be sending to this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is frustrating.

The Flow was giving me the Id of the `KnowledgeArticleVersion`, not the article. (Of course, I had no way to know this since I couldn't find anywhere where it said that I was creating a version and not something else).

So I need to use another Get Record element to get the `KnowledgeArticleId` and try to publish that.

Both the Article and the Version Ids start with `ka0`, so at a glance there is no way to tell which object you are dealing with. (Unlike ContentDocuments and all of its related versions, links and sundry items).